# Best chart for this data?

Tags: data-visualization

I've got this data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AqDm6Izoam4OdF9qekJ6dFlfVjF0QnVoLXFxYXFGTnc&single=true&gid=3&output=html being collected via a google form.
The columns are [Region], [Town], [Area],[Sound Schedule]

[Sound Schedule] is a yes|no column, so I'm thinking I can do a chart that groups that data based on [Sound Schedule] amounts. I'm not sure which chart would be a good fit for this.

Comment: Not a good enough answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the geographic demographic is small you might want to make a map of the area and have two colors for Yes and No (red/blue) That way you could visualize the data better. Similar to the charts they show during elections.

Smilar to this:
[image: Map]

If doing something line/bar based is needed, the best way to show this data may be to display it similar to how google already is doing it, add some colors for the on and off. And potentially add a pie chart to show the percent of cities on and off.